# How do i force user from leaving input box untill the error is resolved or value correct according to validation in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How do i force user from leaving input box untill the error is resolved or value correct according to validation in vue3 ?

i want user not to leave the input box or cursor should not go to another element until the thrown error is resolved in vue3

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: i have a validation on input field and i want user not to leave the field until the user has given a non errror value

Comment: I understand the question. Have you done anything with code so you can show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add blur event, and check, use ref ... if blur and if input has error, focus input.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <form class="field">
      <input
      id="movieInput"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search for a movie"
      ref="movieInput"
      @input="onInput"
      @blur="onBlurInput"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  data: () => ({
    isFieldError: true,
  }),
  methods: {
    onInput(event) {
      const { value } = event.target;
      this.isFieldError = value.length < 3;
    },
    onBlurInput() {
      if (this.isFieldError) {
        this.$refs.movieInput.focus();
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks i have done something similar and it worked